# Which notion of equivalence is being used here?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory

I'm reading [Homotopy associativiy of H-spaces I](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-108-02/S0002-9947-1963-99936-3/S0002-9947-1963-99936-3.pdf) by Stasheff and in the proof of Proposition 2 he says that any map is equivalent to a fibring (in modern day language I think this is either a fibration or a fiber bundle). He refers to Lemma 13 of [this paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/nomura.pdf) by Nomura, where he states that any map $f:X\to Y$ is equivalent to a fibring. The fibring is of the form $p:Z_f\to Y$ where $Z_f$ is constructed in the proof.

I would like to know in what sense these maps are equivalents. The map $f$ need not be a fibring  so this is not an equivalence of fibrings. A homotopy equivalence wouldn't make sense either because the domains are different. I haven't found in any of the linked papers any definition of this equivalence, so does anyone knows what they're talking about?

According to Stashef there should be a map $X\to Z_f$ commuting with $f$ and $p$, so maybe they mean that $f$ is homotopy equivalent to the composition of $p$ with this map.

Comment: See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration , especially "turning a map into a fibration."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By *fibring* Stasheff means Hurewicz fibration. That is a map $p:E\rightarrow B$ which has the homotopy lifting property with respect to all spaces.

By *equivalent to* Stasheff means the following. Given any map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ there is a Hurewicz fibration $p_f:W_f\rightarrow Y$ and inverse homotopy equivalences
$$X\xrightarrow{i} W_f\xrightarrow{q} X$$
such that
$$p_f\circ i=f,\qquad \qquad f\circ q\simeq p_f.$$
It is in the sense of the first equation that $f$ is *equivalent* to $p_f$.

As a model for the space it is standard to take
$$W_f=\{(x,l)\in X\times Y^I\mid f(x)=l(0)\}$$
with
$$p_f(x,l)=l(1).$$
Here $Y^I$ is the space of all maps $I\rightarrow Y$ in the compact-open topology. The map $i$ sends $x$ to the pair $(x,c_{f(x)})$, where $c_{f(x)}$ is the constant path at $f(x)$. The map $q$ is the projection $(x,l)\mapsto x$.

See, eg.  M. Arkowitz's book *Introduction to Homotopy Theory* $\S$3.3 for details.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's all clear now.